# Integrate ffmpeg to unity via plugin OS X and Linux

Tags: linux, macos, unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, wrapper

I need to use a ffmpeg wrapper (so we can use it in unity) for a lecture.
Unfortunately the teachers only provide a solution to do this for Windows.
They are referring to https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen which we should use to generate a wrapper for our OS.

That's where my problems begin: I have downloaded ffmpeg via macport, but I have no idea what to do next?

They only provide the following information:

1. Run dump-expots.cmd to create exports map Run
2. FFmpeg.AutoGen.CppSharpUnsafeGenerator;
3. All files with extension *.g.cs in FFmpeg.AutoGen project will be regenerated.

dump-expots.cmd is clearly not useable on other OS than Windows.

I and also many of my colleagues would be very grateful to get tips how to create the wrapper on OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my colleagues found a solution based on an answer in the unity forum:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/23615/how-to-make-unity-find-dylib-files.html

The trick is to install ffmpeg (MacPort/Homebrew) and rename the *.dylib files to *.bundle.

It is a really strange solution but it seems to work. changing the format of a picture and encoding a video worked just fine.